# Deserialize List to unmodifiable collection with gson

Tags: java, list, deserialization, gson

I wish to have all `List`s deserialized to unmodifiable collections.

Here is my class that I am deserializing:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public final mylist = Collections.unmodifiablelist(new ArrayList());
}
```

How I deserialize:

```
MyClass inst = (new Gson()).fromJson("{mylist:[\"firstString\"]}", MyClass.class);
```

I don't want to have to create a register a type adapter for all the 100 classes that use a `List`, so is there a way to globally override the deserializable of `List` for that instance of `Gson`?

Comment: Where is the type of field `mylist`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with an adapter factory too, but shorter code :

```
class MyAdapter implements TypeAdapterFactory {

  @Override
  public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(final Gson gson, final TypeToken<T> tokenType) {
    final TypeAdapter<T> delegate = gson.getDelegateAdapter(this, tokenType);

    return new TypeAdapter<T>() {
      @Override
      public void write(JsonWriter out, T value) throws IOException {
        delegate.write(out, value);
      }

      @Override
      public T read(JsonReader arg0) throws IOException {
        T t = delegate.read(arg0);
        if (List.class.isAssignableFrom(tokenType.getRawType())) {
          List<?> list = (List<?>) t;

          return (T) Collections.unmodifiableList(list);
        }

        return t;
      }
    };
  }
}
```

Then, as usual, register it :

```
Gson g = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapterFactory(new MyAdapter()).create();
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just follow the JavaBean standards and just return unmodifiable lists?

```
public class MyClass {
    private List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();

    public void setMyList(List<String> list) {
        this.myList = list;
    }

    public Collection<String> getMyList() {
        return Collections.unmodifiablelist(this.myList);
    }
}
```

Comment: ...because the `myList` instance is used internally aswell...I'd prefer for sanity reasons, to have it unmodifiable.

Comment: imho, if you can't trust your own class not to make modifications, you have bigger issues

Comment: ...it's not a trust thing...more about about reasoning should someone come to edit my class at a later date....if it's unmodifiable, it will make the developer stop and think why it was done...